# Can't access Media Library folder items from within Content Editor despite folder containing items

Tags: content-editor, media-library

When attempting to set an image for a field in Content Editor, the media library shows no items to pick from:

[image]

However there are in fact items in this location:

[image]

I am also able to access these items when accessing the folder via Media Library. I did not build this site so I am not sure where the problem lies - an account issue in User Manager, Security Editor, or Access Viewer? Or the configuration of the item's template? Or something else?

Comment: Is this an issue with the indexing?

Comment: Do you use admin or other user when opening that dialog in ML? Are you sure you have permissions to see children (Descendants) for that folder? Check this article https://www.valtech.com/insights/sitecore-security-part-2-the-security-editor-and-access-viewer/ Security Editor chapter - Step 2

Comment: Are your images SVG ? Could this be the case : https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1670 ?

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the default "Home" item being deleted.

I removed it thinking it wasn't necessary since it has no child items and none of the sites pointed to this item as their root. Restoring the item from the Recycle Bin fixed the issue. Sitecore support also provided a package should it be needed. More info here: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0516102

Thanks to anyone who suggested other areas to look into.

An additional note: if the package provided by Sitecore support is used, and you have another site with a root item named Home, simply rename the default home item to anything else (i.e. HomeDefault"). The bug is fixed so long as this default home item is there; it can be called anything:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said this issue might be caused by indexing as sitecore uses the master index to get these results. If you take a look at the Search.log files you will see entries like these:

```
Query [sitecore_master_index]: &search=((template_1:(f1828a2c7e5d4bbd98ca320474871548) OR template_1:(daf085e8602e43a68299038ff171349f) OR template_1:(c97ba92380094858bdd5d8be5fccecf7) OR template_1:(eb3fb96cd56b4ac997f8f07b24bb9bf7)) AND language_1:(en))&$filter=(path_1/any(t:t eq '3d6658d8a0bf4e75b3e2d050fabcf4e1'))&queryType=full&facet=calculateddimension&facet=templatename_1&$skip=0&$top=20&$count=true
```

Can you try to rebuild your `sitecore_master_index` and see if the issue is still happening? Depending if you use SOLR or Azure you should also verify the configuration of the master index in `\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config` or `\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Master.config` to see if the media items are being indexed:

```
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have rebuilt the master and media indices for master and web databases and also checked that my configuration matched your screenshot. Unfortunately I still cannot see items.